# I want to filter the def 'getAmountRating(self):' function

Tags: django, django-filter

I built the class Restaurant where you can find the 'def getAmountRating(self):' function.
This function should be used as a keyword in my django_filter.

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
restaurant_picture = models.ImageField(null=True, default='dashboard-BG.jpg')
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

address = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
houseNumber = models.IntegerField(default=1)

city = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
state = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="86444")

tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
affordability = models.FloatField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(3), MinValueValidator(1)], null=True)
objects = models.Manager()

def getAverageRating(self):
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    avg = 0
    count = 0
    for i in comments:
        if i.restaurant == self:
            avg += i.ratings
            if count is 0:
                count += 1
            else:
                avg = avg / 2
    if avg is not 0:
        avg = round(avg)
    return avg
```

In the filter

```
class RestaurantFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

rating = NumberFilter(field_name="getAverageRating", lookup_expr="gte")

class Meta:
    model = Restaurant
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['location', 'restaurant_picture', 'address', 'houseNumber', 'state']
```

I already had to accept that this is not working as I'd like to.

As a fix I looked up some solutions but those solutions did not work.
For example I built an other class containing the def getAverageRating function and referenced this class in Restaurant as a  -  **averageRating = RestaurantRating()**  -  which did not work.

I don't think its relevant but here is the views.py

```
def restaurants(request):
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all()

foods = Food.objects.all()
comments = Comment.objects.all()

myFilter = RestaurantFilter(request.GET, queryset=restaurants)
restaurants = myFilter.qs

context = {'restaurants': restaurants, 'myFilter': myFilter, 'foods': foods, 'comments': comments}
return render(request, 'accounts/restaurants.html', context)
```

I hope someone finds the time to help me with my issue.
Thx in advande.

Comment: You *can't* filter on functions or properties. A queryset is translated into an database query, and the database does not know anything about properties or methods.

Comment: Your average also is not a valid average. You each time divide `avg` by two? This means that the *last* comment contributes for 50%, the one-but last with 25%, the one after that by 12.5%, etc.

Comment: Can you share your `Comment` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not filter, annotate or aggregate on properties or methods. Properties and methods are defined on the Python/Django model, but the database does not know anything about these. Since `Queryset`s are translated into database queries, using a method, property does not make much sense.

It would not be efficient anyway if it was possible. It would mean you fetch *all* the `Restaurant`s in memory and then you filter on each restaurant at the Python/Django level. Python is not ideal to filter huge amounts of data, databases are designed to do this.

We however do *not* need this. A database can determine the average of a related field itself. It has *aggregates* and it can group by to obtain the average *per* restaurant. In SQL you would construct a query like:

```
SELECT restaurant.*, AVG(comment.rating)
FROM restaurant
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment ON comment.restaurant_id = restaurant.id
GROUP BY restaurant.id
```

you can do this with Django as well. Indeed, we can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the restaurants with the average rating of the restaurants with:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

Restaurant.objects.annotate(
    avg_rating=Avg('comment__ratings')
)
```

We can use this in our `FilterSet` with:

```
class RestaurantFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    rating = NumberFilter(field_name='avg_rating', lookup_expr='gte')
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        exclude = [
            'location'
          , 'restaurant_picture'
          , 'address'
          , 'houseNumber'
          , 'state'
          ]
```

and in the view we thus can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

def restaurants(request):
    restaurants = Restaurant.objects.annotate(
        avg_rating=Avg('comment__ratings')
    )

    foods = Food.objects.all()
    comments = Comment.objects.all()

    myFilter = RestaurantFilter(request.GET, queryset=restaurants)
    restaurants = myFilter.qs

    context = {'restaurants': restaurants, 'myFilter': myFilter, 'foods': foods, 'comments': comments}
    return render(request, 'accounts/restaurants.html', context)
```